# How can I compile a library with Carthage using the latest beta of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, carthage

I am testing out Swift 3 with Xcode 8 Beta (8S128d), which leads me to a situation where my Carthage-built libraries are not compatible with the source base.

`Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'SwiftValidator' and try again`.

How can I configure Carthage so that `carthage update` uses the Beta compiler rathe rthan the standard one?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I moved the Beta into /Applications.

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/` sets the Xcode to be used to the beta.

`carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` builds the libraries for iOS and prevents Carthage from downloading existing (yet incompatible) precompiled binaries.

Comment: I get the following types of errors when running the 2nd step

The following build commands failed:
 CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/noah/Desktop/XCode/PKS+SS/Carthage/Checkouts/SQLite.swift/SQLite/Typed/CoreFunctions.swift

 CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/noah/Desktop/XCode/PKS+SS/Carthage/Checkouts/SQLite.swift/SQLite/Extensions/R*Tree.swift

 CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/noah/Desktop/XCode/PKS+SS/Carthage/Checkouts/SQLite.swift/SQLite/Core/Blob.swift

(5 failures)

Comment: @noah  check this thread out https://github.com/Alecrim/AlecrimCoreData/issues/35